# How do you say "I also have lots of news to tell you" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

Could anyone tell me how you would say "I also have lots (of news) to tell you" in German, when speaking to friends who you haven't seen in quite a long time?

Comment: relevant meta discussion: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/what-is-a-phrase-request-and-when-do-we-accept-it-as-on-topic?cb=1

Answer (score 4):

You could say

> "Ich habe Dir viel zu erzählen."

or, if you want to emphasize the importance of your news:

> "Ich muß Dir ganz viel erzählen."

Comment: Vielen Dank für ihre Antwort

Comment: "Ganz viel" ist Quantität, nicht Qualität. "Ganz wichtiges zu erzählen" wäre richtig, wenn es wichtig ist.

Comment: @user unknown I thought about something important/ urgent for the speaker that would be stressed with *muss* and *ganz*

Comment: Ein dringendes Mitteilungsbedürfnis des Sprechers ist aber etwas anderes als dringende Nachrichten für den Empfänger. "Ich muss Dir ganz viel erzählen." heißt eher, dass man viel Tratsch austauschen möchte. **Ganz** viel unterstreicht, dass es viel ist.

Comment: @userunknown Totally agree that this is rather chit-chat German :) However, Emilia aksed for something to be used among friends, that's why I came up with this

Comment: Auch unter Freunden kann ein Interesse bestehen zwischen viel zu erzählen und wichtiges zu erzählen zu unterscheiden. Wer nur eine wichtige Sache zu erzählen hat wird kaum sagen 'ganz viel' um die Wichtigkeit zu unterstreichen, auch nicht unter Freunden.

Answer (score 2):

Man kann beispielsweise sagen: "Es gibt viel Neues zu berichten." oder "Ich habe viele Neuigkeiten."

Comment: Ahh, danke schön. And that would be quite casual and informal?

Comment: @EmiliaBell Looks more like direct translations, I doubt that the news are exciting, if any of these variants were used.

Comment: @Emilia Bell: What I suggested can certainly by used in a casual, informal situation, but I'd prefer that in writing, e.g. a personal letter or mail. What Marzipanherz has suggested fits way better when *speaking* to a person, which is what you had asked for.